# How to bake stylized anime lines on an object?

Tags: texture-baking, baking, lineart, lines

So I am trying to find a way to bake the outlines that I've created here. However, I am having a little bit of trouble. I learned how to create these stylized lines around my asset and I want to bake the outlines into a map so I can export it out of Blender. Here is the tutorial I am following (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5wu_SvCCX_U).

I've tried baking it into different types of texture maps to no avail. Does anyone know how to bake these stylized lines?

Here is a DropBox link (https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/plmk34122c2wadcs343h6/h?rlkey=ful4g298u2yibrtidgqz1cg4u&dl=0) to the Blend file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

there is no way to bake outlines of this style onto a texture, as they aren't 2d effects or decals added on top of a model, but are done using additional geometry to give the appearance of outlines, they are fully 3d and extend off of the model entirely.

however, if you apply the solidify modifier, then it will add the geometry of the outlines into the mesh itself, and you can export that into programs other than blender.